# Specifying a null model for path analysis

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, path-model

I'm struggling with the final step (or technically what should have been the first step?) of making a null model. In the article, the authors state that the null represents a situation where none of the variables predict the other (they're all independent) and then they go on to present an AIC for the null as well.

I'm confused because I don't know how/ didn't know it was possible to build a model where no variables predict the other in path analysis. At first I thought it meant the variables can only predict themselves, but I tried that and get a lot of errors so I'm guessing that's the wrong way to go about this. Can anyone provide some guidance on what a null model is (and the syntax for building a null model)?

I've included an example of one of my predictive models and my possibly wrong null if that helps and am happy to provide other details

```
mod1 <-' 
LScore ~ Weightloss + GRS 
Novelty ~ LScore
Nurse ~ LScore
ProVar ~ Novelty
AFF ~ LScore + ProVar + Nurse'

Null <- '
GRS ~ GRS
Weightloss ~ Weightloss
LScore ~ LScore 
Novelty ~ Novelty
Nurse ~ Nurse
ProVar ~ ProVar
AFF ~ AFF'
```

Comment: Questions about syntax are off topic here. But there's a deeper question about what the appopriate null model should be. I've edited the question to reflect this deeper question, and tried to answer it.

Comment: if you're getting errors, and want help, you need to say what you ran and what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to CrossValidated.

There are a few different ways to think about the null model. Your approach is one way to do it - and that's the approach that some people / programs use.

Other people / programs say that the x-variable correlations are not really part of the model,so they should be included in the null model (I think that Lavaan uses this approach).

However, the Lavaan program should give you the fit for the null model, so you don't really have to estimate it yourself.

For some clever thinking about null models in SEM, see this paper (which, IIRC, is fairly approachable.).  https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Keith_Widaman/publication/10764067_On_Specifying_the_Null_Model_for_Incremental_Fit_Indices_in_Structural_Equation_Modeling/links/02e7e516c4ef70fdc1000000/On-Specifying-the-Null-Model-for-Incremental-Fit-Indices-in-Structural-Equation-Modeling.pdf